# Admin Bar CSS left over after removal

Tags: admin-bar

I am using the following code to remove the admin bar (client request).

```
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
```

Trouble is, it leaves some autogenerating CSS, which places a massive white line at the top of my page in its place (via a 28px top margin rule). How can I turn this off as well?

Comment: You could use jQuery to control the css, i guess

Comment: I'm echoing @anu, please go back and review your questions and please reward the people who took the time to give you an answer by accepting the best answer and up-voting any helpful answers. *See paragraphs 3 & 4 after the header "[How do I ask a Question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)"*

Comment: Could you trace where exactly extra CSS comes from? What file or script? From looking over code that `__return_false`  snippet **should** kill all CSS and JS that admin bar uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To completely remove the Admin bar deregister the js and css using wp_degregister_script and remove the action.

```
if (!is_admin() && !current_user_can('add_users')){
    wp_deregister_script( 'admin-bar' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'admin-bar' );
    remove_action('wp_footer','wp_admin_bar_render',1000);
}
```

Comment: The script is part of a toggle in the admin area, so different users can turn it on and off (why is this not default behaviour?). Would I run into problems reinstating the admin bar using this method?

Comment: Also, strangely, my hack to fix the issue has been to remove the wp_head, am I to assume that the admin bar attaches to the footer? Because my hack (albeit ill advised) works well.

Comment: The Admin Bar hooks into `wp_footer()`, rather than into `wp_head()`. Note: removing either of these hooks is a *bad idea*.

Comment: I did say that :)

Comment: This will not show the admin bar, but it will keep the top 28 pixel margin which was the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think you added this filter *too late* (on `init`?), so that the initialization does happen, but the rest does not.

The three places that check `show_admin_bar` (via [`is_admin_bar_showing()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L332)) are:

- [`_wp_admin_bar_init()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L8), called on `init`. This creates an instance of [the `WP_Admin_Bar` class](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php), which [hooks into `wp_head`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php#L39) and [adds the 28px margin at the top](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L303).
- [`get_body_class()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L503) adds the `admin-bar` class to the body tag (weird that this is not done by hooking into `body_class`?)
- [`wp_admin_bar_render()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L41) does the actual rendering. If you disable this but not the first one, you get an empty area at the top.

Because `_wp_admin_bar_init()` is called on `init`, you will be *too late* if you also add the `show_admin_bar` filter on `init`, unless you change the priority.

This will not render the admin bar, but still add the 28px margin:

```
add_filter( 'init', 'wpse13875_init' );
function wpse13875_init()
{
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

This will completely disable the admin bar, because it will be executed before `_wp_admin_bar_init()`:

```
add_filter( 'init', 'wpse13875_init', 9 );
function wpse13875_init()
{
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/77639/disable-the-admin-bar/77648#77648), was a complete solution including unload the scripts and styles. The hook remove the admin bar, but not the load of js and css.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just override the CSS - probably the easiest way - add a display: none to whatever the admin bar selector is

Comment: The admin bar css is dynamically added to the *html element with javascript.  It will override any attempt to override it.