# Wordpress 3.1's admin bar disappears only leaving its 28 px padding (in ubuntu)!

Tags: admin, customization

At the begining, I thought there was an issue with my HTML or CSS files. But then I realized that other people using Wordpress 3.1 had the same problem (check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865100/html-tag-has-28px-to-margin-which-seems-to-come-from-nowhere)).

The admin bar disappears when I click another 'Pages' or 'Posts,' but it leaves its 28px padding at the top of the page.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with folder's permission issues in ubuntu (I'm using ubuntu 11.04). I did `chmod -R 777` to my `www` folder (the default folder for my `locahhost`), but I'm still having the same issue.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Admin Bar CSS left over after removal](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/admin-bar-css-left-over-after-removal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that `wp_footer()` is being called in all template files, and that the Admin Bar javascript and CSS are being properly hooked into the document head.

Comment: Thanks for helping again. But how can I verify that?

Comment: For `wp_footer()`, look in the `footer.php` template file. For the document head output, I would just look at the browser source, and compare the output in the document head on the Page on which the Admin Bar appears, against the same output in the document head on the Page on which the Admin Bar doesn't appear.