# wp_head function causes 30px blank space

Tags: css, wp-head

I want my outer-wrapper to be full screen, but if use wp_head(); function it causes nearly 30px blank space from the top. If I use #outer-wrapper: margin: -30px auto; this time there is 30px blank space from the bottom.

here is screenshot:

[image]

This is my header.php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: The culprit is likely a function *hooked* to `wp_head`. Track the hooked function down and debug from there. Perhaps the function is outputting some HTML that's being affected by your CSS?

Comment: actually this another answer is like solving my issue, but I'm not sure.It says that wp_head function keeps you stay logged in, but admin bar doesn't appear.

Comment: The `wp_head()` function is absolutely necessary for all kinds of things, for example outputting scripts and styles. Can you post the source generated for the <head> element of your theme. This might help.

Comment: This is my header.php codes
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

and I added this function wp_footer(); to footer.php then admin bar appeared on the top, quickly I logged out after that blank space disappeared. Maybe this was the problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to provide the link above I mentioned: [Link: why-is-wp-head-creating-a-top-margin-at-the-top-of-my-theme-header](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17643/why-is-wp-head-creating-a-top-margin-at-the-top-of-my-theme-header)

Comment: Sounds like the missing call to wp_footer() was indeed the issue, which other folks also experienced in the question you linked to.